# Test if python's builtin __mul__ was called using mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-mock

I have a method where I am converting dollars to cents before calling an api.

```
# money.py
def send_money(dollars):
    cents = dollars * 100
    return send_money_to_api(cents)
```

* This is not exactly my code. But this is sufficient for demonstration.

`dollars`'s type is `decimal.Decimal` as it's actually coming from `django`'s `DecimalField`.

**I want to ensure that I am multiplying the amount by 100. I tried testing this using mock**

```
import mock

from money import send_money

@mock.patch('money.operator.__mul__')
@mock.patch('money.send_money_to_api')
def test_money(self, api_mock, mul_mock):
    send_money(20)

    assert api_mock.called
    mul_mock.assert_any_call(20, 100)
```

It fails saying,

```
E   ImportError: No module named operator
```

How do I test this?

Comment: What else would it call? Are you worried about someone passing `dollars` as an instance of a class with its own `__mul__`? What is it you're concerned about?

Comment: I am concerned that some developer/I will forget to do the conversion.

Comment: What is `dollars`'s type? There isn't a builtin `__mul__`, but every objects have their own `__mul__` function. So if you want to mock this function, you need to mock `dollars`'s class.

Comment: `dollars`'s type is `int`

Comment: Wait. It's actually `decimal.Decimal` because it comes from `django`'s `DecimalField`

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to test that `send_money`is called?

Comment: It's actually important that money was converted inside it.

Comment: I fixed it. Added the answer. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this after some great help from comments. Special thanks to [@Sraw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5588279/sraw).

```
@mock.patch.object(decimal.Decimal, '__mul__')
@mock.patch('money.send_money_to_api')
def test_money(self, api_mock, mul_mock):
    send_money(20)

    assert api_mock.called
    mul_mock.assert_any_call(100)
```

An advantage of mocking `decimal.Decimal` instance method `__mul__` is I can truly ensure that all the `DecimalField` values (which are mostly amounts) from database are converted.